# Tikz draw section of circle enclosed by x-axis and horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to tikz and I want to draw the following shaded area that is enclosed by the line y = 1, the x-axis, and the circle defined by x^2 + y^2 <= 2. The following figure depicts the desired result. How do I do this?

[image: What I want in Tikz]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: @Tordir  please have alook at the answer if it meets your requirement

Answer (score 1):

In general I would recommend following the advice given by Tobi, but this is quite simple, so I'll answer anyway. I'll also note that if you haven't looked at the tutorials at the start of the [TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), I'd recommend doing so. The first of those (chapter 2) will teach you everything needed to make a diagram like that.

---

Drawing the axes shouldn't be a problem I guess, that's just two straight lines.

For the cut off circle, it consists of two arcs and two straight lines. To draw an arc you can use

```
arc[start angle=<degrees>, end angle=<degrees>, radius=<length>]
```

which will draw counter-clockwise the part of a circle from `start angle` to `end angle`. (You can also do `arc[start angle=<degrees>, delta angle=<degrees>, radius=<length>]`, where the `delta angle` indicates the arc length in degrees.)

Lets say you start drawing on the right most point of the circle. You know that is at `(2,0)`, so you start with

```
\draw (2,0) ...
```

You want to add a label below this point, and while it can be added later, it might be just as convenient in this case to add it at the same time. Text is added using `node [<options>] {<text>}`:

```
\draw (2,0) node[below] {2} ...
```

(If adding nodes separately, you can do `\node [<options>] at (<coordinate>) {<text>};`.)

From there you want to draw an arc covering 30 degrees (because sin(30) = 0.5), starting at an angle of zero. Following what was said above:

```
\draw (2,0) node[below] {2} 
       arc[start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=2] node[right] {1}...
```

where I also added a label right of the endpoint of that arc.

The next part is to draw a straight line to where the left arc starts. While you could calculate the x/y-coordinates, either manually or directly in the coordinate, it's more convenient to use polar coordinates, which are specified with `(<angle> : <radius>)`:

```
  \draw (2,0) node[below] {2}
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=2] node[right] {1}
        -- (150:2) ...
```

Now you just draw the second arc, adding a `node` for the label, and finally a straight line back to start. When drawing closed paths, instead of repeating the first coordinate use `cycle`:

```
\draw (2,0) node[below] {2}
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=2] node[right] {1}
        -- (150:2)
        arc[start angle=150, end angle=180, radius=2] node[below] {2}
        -- cycle;
```

`\draw` alone gives you just a black line, but you can specify color and fill in the options:

```
\filldraw [
  fill=brown!80!black,
  draw=red,
  very thick
  ] 
  (2,0) node[below] {2}
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=2] node[right] {1}
        -- (150:2)
        arc[start angle=150, end angle=180, radius=2] node[below] {2}
        -- cycle;
```

(Using `\filldraw` instead of `\draw` isn't strictly necessary when specifying both `fill=<color>` and `draw=<color>` as in this case.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\path [
  fill=brown!80!black,
  draw=red,
  very thick
  ] 
  (2,0) node[below] {2}
        arc[start angle=0, end angle=30, radius=2] node[right] {1}
        -- (150:2)
        arc[start angle=150, end angle=180, radius=2] node[below] {2}
        -- cycle;
  
  
\draw [thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [thick] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer with tkz-euclide is added

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or another class
\usepackage{xcolor} % before tikz or tkz-euclide if necessary

\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % no need to load TikZ

\usetikzlibrary{babel} %if there are problems with the active characters
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    %define the origin O -- radius A
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(1.41,0){A}
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](O,A)

    %draw the semicircle
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation= center O angle 180](A)
    \tkzGetPoint{B}
    \tkzDrawArc[line width=0.1pt, white](O,A)(B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](B)
    %draw the line at y=1
    \tkzDefPoint(1,0){A'}
    \tkzDefPoint(-1,0){B'}
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[A'](90:1){A''}
    \tkzDefShiftPoint[B'](90:1){B''}
    \tkzDrawSegment[red,line width=1pt](A'',B'')    
    %draw the arc perimeter line
    \tkzDrawArc[red,line width=1pt](O,A)(A'')
    \tkzDrawArc[red,line width=1pt](O,B'')(B)
    %color the fill inside
    \fill[red!40] (-1,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \tkzFillSector[rotate,color=red!40](O,A)(45)
    \tkzFillSector[rotate,color=red!40](O,B)(-45)
    %draw the center axis -horizontal and vertical
    \tkzDrawLine(A,B)
    \tkzDefLine[orthogonal =through O](B,A)\tkzGetPoint{X}
    \tkzDrawLine(O,X)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```